# how to use a placeholder in tinymce textarea

Tags: tinymce, placeholder

how can i use a placeholder with tinymce. here is my problem.

I am using cyrillic letter like Я I manually enter the HTML entity numeric code in the editor (&#1071) and i don't want tinymce to convert it to an html entity. So how would i save it in tinymce with a placeholder "[swap]" and then inside psql do a replace.
I have to this for several entries.
update
I tried : entity_encoding : "raw"   without success

Answer (score 1):

You can use a html overlay as well, which is easier:

Like:

```
<div id="placeholder" style="position: relative; top: 20px;">My Placeholder</div>

<textarea id="tinybox" name="tinymcebox"></textarea>
```

With jQuery you can create:

```
$("#placeholder").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
$("#tinybox").click(function(){
    $('#placeholder').hide();
});
```

Then you know sure the special character is shown well.

Comment: it is shown well in the text editor. but an alert on the textarea value shows ÃÂ¯. that's why I were thinking of a placeholder. but i don't know how to implement it in a way that i can save the Я in tinymce and then inside psql do a replace that looks for that and replaces it with an html entity code.

Comment: @mamesaye I'm afraid ```placeholder``` is a specific HTML term. And the answer above is rather poor... It doesn't restore the `My Placeholder` text after the content is back to empty.